# Not able to remove an object from array of object

Tags: vue.js

[image]

I would like to remove items from the Array of objects but I am not able to iterate through modelObjs

```
 handleMultiSelectSelection(event, id, opts,disable,modelObjs) {
 modelObjs.forEach(function(modelObj, index) {
        self.$delete(modelObjs[index], "Key");         
   }); 
}
```

here is the error I am getting

"TypeError: modelObjs.forEach is not a function"

Comment: are you sure this is where the problem is as the variable names don't match `modelObjs` vs `objs`

Comment: Its a typo,I have updated it...error is the same

Comment: try console log(objs). check if the value is always array, or in some situation it will be undefined or null?

Comment: the problem is at first i will be initializing the modelObjs with a key value pair. Thus it is not an array instead its just an object. and hence iteration is not possible. modelObjs becomes array when I clicks on multiselect drop down to add items....Solved the above error by initializing as an array of object